# GoogleMap scrolls with DraggableScrollableSheet in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I am placing a `DraggableScrollableSheet` on top of `GoogleMap` widget. It behaves as expected in Android, however on Web the Map scrolls along with the sheet.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapPage> createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          const GoogleMap(
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
          ),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            maxChildSize: 1,
            minChildSize: 0.1,
            initialChildSize: 0.5,
            builder: (context, scrollController) {
              return ListView(
                controller: scrollController,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  100,
                  (index) => ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      child: Text('I am item no. $index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What should I do so that when scrolling on the sheet, the map does not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter gestureRecognizers and check

```
   GoogleMap(
                    gestureRecognizers: Set()
                      ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
                      ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
                      ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
                      ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(() => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
                  ),
```

Comment: This did not change behaviour.